# What are the sports facilities at the Orlando Disney World?

Tags: football, basketball, nba, mls, covid-19

I've been both a little amazed and confused the past couple of weeks as the NBA and MLS plan to resume play in Orlando after COVID-19 related shutdowns halted the leagues' seasons.
Both leagues are to restart as they hold games at Disney World in Orlando.
What has made me confused - as someone who's never been to Disney World and thinks it's not much more than a massive theme park with some other entertainments - is how are the 2 leagues accommodated at the same time?

We're talking about 100s of players, with multiple games happening everyday (at least in the beginning), hospitality for them and all the coaches, trainers, etc.
I guess all basketball games can happen on 1 court so long as there are no simultaneous games. Soccer would be harder as the pitch quality would be sabotaged with continuous use.
So there would have to be either many fields, or just one artificial turf.
Can artificial turf withstand multiple games a day and still be in shape for top tier matches for weeks? And when teams don't play, they need to practice which requires having few other courts and fields, as well as gyms, and administrative facilities for team meetings, massages, entertainment, etc for many teams all at once.
Since there won't be any fans, the facilities don't need to have capacities for 10s of thousands of fans as usual. But I assume the quality for the athletes should be just as good as their home stadiums/arenas to keep injury rates low, and avoid lower quality of game play.

So are there really enough top tier sports facilities at Orlando Disney World to host both leagues at the same time?
If so, why does it have so much high quality sports facilities? Has it always been a hub for sports?
Or strictly sports talking, the facilities aren't as high level and these leagues and players acknowledge that, yet agreed to play there to finish their seasons?

Comment: Yes, artificial turf can hold up that well. Daily usage of high level for months is within design limits, and can be done for years before replacement, on a high quality surface.

Answer (score 4):

Disney World Orlando, whilst being renowned as every kids' favourite theme park, is also home to the [ESPN Wide World of Sport Complex](https://www.espnwwos.com/)

This complex includes sporting facilities such as:

- **The Arena** - an indoor complex that can be converted to host 6+ regulation-sized Basketball courts
- **HP Field House** - another indoor complex that can host Basketball (is the current host of the [Orlando Invitational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlando_Invitational) college basketball tournament)
- **Marathon Sports Fields** - an outdoor complex comprising of 12 fields, 4 multi-purpose fields, 4 Baseball fields, and 4 Softball fields. Some of these fields are used for the [Walt Disney Pro Soccer Classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walt_Disney_World_Pro_Soccer_Classic) pre-season tournament, which feature some MLS teams.
- There are also facilities for field and track athletics, gymnastics, field hockey, tennis...

[Other Venues at ESPN WWOS](https://www.espnwwos.com/complex/venues/)

[Facilities Map](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/digital-media-prod-usw2/media/espnwwos/pdf/complex/January2019ESPNWWOSmap.pdf)

Comment: Great, detailed answer - and amazing how big this is!  I knew it had a lot from my niece going there to play soccer tournaments, but ...